# Create key/value pairs from filter menu using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown that allows users to filter their query.

```
<select id="bike_category_filter" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Gender">
    <option value="Mens">Mens</option>
    <option value="Womens">Womens</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Type">
    <option value="Mountain Bike">Mountain Bike</option>
      <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
      <option value="Road">Road</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I am looking to send selected options in a hash, for example

```
{ gender: 'Mens', style: ['Mountain Bike', 'Road'] }
```

So upon click of option `Men || Womens` i would like to add that with the key `Gender` and for any of the types I would like to add to `style: ['values here']`.

How would I achieve such a thing, and what methods can I use from the jQuery library?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = {
    gender: '',
    style: []
};

$('#bike_category_filter').change(function() {
    var selected = $('option:selected', this),
        val = selected.val(),
        index = '';

    if (!val) {
        return;
    }

    switch (selected.parent()[0].label) {
        case 'Gender':
            result.gender = val;
            // reset style for selected gender
            result.style = [];
            break;
        case 'Type':
            (index = result.style.indexOf(val) === -1) 
                ? result.gender && result.style.push(val)
                : result.style.splice(index, 1);
            break;
    }

    $(this).val(result.style.concat([result.gender]));
    $('code').html(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

```css
select {
  height: 130px;}

code {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="bike_category_filter" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Gender">
    <option value="Mens">Mens</option>
    <option value="Womens">Womens</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Type">
    <option value="Mountain Bike">Mountain Bike</option>
      <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
      <option value="Road">Road</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<code></code>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems much more inline with what I wanted to achieve

Comment: This solution is fine if you have static `optgroup`s, but it's easy enough to loop over the `optgroup` tags to generate the result object's keys and get the selected options within it; check my answer for a generic solution

Comment: +1 @kenbellows your answer is very good. Yes, i did it based on statics "Gender" and "Type" `optgroup`s according to the question..

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm is:

- each time the user selects/deselects a value:

  - reset `result` to an empty object
  - for each `<optgroup>` tag:

    - store the value of the `label` attribute in the variable `groupName`
    - initialize a new empty `groupSelections` array
    - for each `<option>` tag within the `<optgroup>` that has been selected by the user:

      - add the value of the `option` to `groupSelections`
    - set `result[groupName] = groupSelections`

At the end, you should have one property in the `result` object for each `optgroup`, and each of those properties should be an array listing the values of the selected `option`s within that `optgroup`.

Here it is in code:

```js
var result;
$('#bike_category_filter').change(function() {
  result = {};
  $(this).find('optgroup').each(function() {
    var groupName = $(this).attr('label');
    var groupSelections = [];
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
      groupSelections.push($(this).val());
    });
    result[groupName] = groupSelections;
  });
  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="bike_category_filter" multiple="multiple" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
  <optgroup label="Gender">
    <option value="Mens">Mens</option>
    <option value="Womens">Womens</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Type">
    <option value="Mountain Bike">Mountain Bike</option>
      <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
      <option value="Road">Road</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<p><code id="result"></code></p>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the only thing that doesn't suit what I want it to do is that when i select mens and then Road, mens is removed... But that's ok, it is a good answer and has got me thinking on how i approach this

Comment: Do you mean that when you select Road, Men's is no longer highlighted, or do you mean that if you select Men's and then Road, both are highlighted but only Road shows up in the object?

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how the `<select multiple="multiple">` element works. In order to select multiple items in the `select`, you need to hold down either the `Shift` key or the `Ctrl` key. Try clicking "Mens", then holding down `Ctrl` and clicking "Road"; that should do what you want. This is just built-in browser functionality, and there isn't anything you can do about that, at least without some deep, ugly hackery that you probably don't want anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var styles = {
    "men": ['Mountain Bike', 'Road'],
    "women": [...]
};
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var gender =  $( "select option:selected" ).val();
    $("your elment").addClass(styles[gender].join(" "));
});
```

I would recommend you to create a style object as above and set the genders as the key and the array as the value.

When ever a user change is selection the `change` callback will be called and then this `$( "select option:selected" ).val();` will return the value of the selected element (in our case the gender).
`styles` is an object when you use this syntax `styles["men"]` you will get the value for the men key.

Comment: thanks, I understand what you mean with creating the object ready to receive data, I have done `var categories = { "gender": [], "styles": [] };` but I cant work out what is happening with the change function, how do i determine what is a gender and what is a style ?